# Plot that comprises categorical data variables and before/ after numerical comparison

Tags: r, database, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataset with 5 categorical variables that relate to before/after numerical data. Is there any way to plot all the information in a single plot? I need to present as much data as possible in the least number of figures and I already have many figures, so it is really necessary to summarize my results. Any ideas of how can I do this?

Here is an example of my data.

| kind_meas | cause_variat_turb | associated_condit | kind_particle | unit | med_turb_contr | med_turb_antrop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| repeat_time | dam_removal |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 39.24 | 211.19 |
| repeat_time | dam_removal |  | suspended_solids | NTU | 3.93 | 334.35 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 48.57 | 1405 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 103.8 | 203 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 162.7 | 1506.5 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 78.14 | 950.7 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 63.2 | 2285.7 |
| repeat_time | dam_flush |  | suspended_solids | FNU | 50.92 | 1372.9 |
| repeat_time | sediment_washout | el_nino | suspended_solids | TSS | 54 | 25.2 |
| dif_places | deforestation |  | suspended_solids | NTU | 2.6 | 3 |
| dif_places | deforestation |  | suspended_solids | TSS | 4.2 | 5.8 |
| repeat_time | mining_dam_break | copper_gold | tailing | NTU | 0.29 | 116.54 |
| repeat_time | drought |  | algal_biomass | NTU | 2.87 | 9.11 |
| repeat_time | wetland_restoration | wastewater_effluent | suspended_solids | TSS | 3.16 | 9.46 |
| repeat_time | fire |  | ashes | TSS | 12.92 | 8.41 |
| dif_places | best_management_practices | cattle_grazing | suspended_solids | TDS | 382.32 | 251.22 |